# Message (user) attribute 'tracestate' must contain a non-empty value of type 'String'

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Getting **Message (user) attribute 'tracestate' must contain a non-empty value of type 'String'** while trying to push the data in AWS SQS.

Using below body and function to push the data

Function used

```
import aws, { SQS } from 'aws-sdk';
import { ServiceConfigurationOptions } from 'aws-sdk/lib/service';
 
 
export default abstract class AbstractSQSPublisherService {
  protected sqs: SQS;
  private options: Parameters<typeof aws.config.update>[0];

  constructor(protected queueUrl: string, options: ServiceConfigurationOptions) {
    this.options = options;
    this.sqs = new SQS({ ...options, apiVersion: '2012-11-05' });
  }

  protected async publishToSqs(body: Record<string, unknown>) {
    await this.sqs
      .sendMessage({
        QueueUrl: this.queueUrl,
        MessageBody: JSON.stringify(body),
      })
      .promise();
  }
}
```

Unable to find out why this issue is happening? For normal body like {notificationId: 2345} works well but sometimes it throws error shown above.

Comment: Have you tried to logging the body when this error occurs?

Comment: Yes, body is  `{notificationId: 2345}`. @JulienAmbrosio. sometimes it works sometime it doesn't. Unable to reproduce on test environment but it throws error on prod

Comment: Sandy bhai mushkil he yaha Github pe raise karo https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues